# SQL join row not possible "Invalid column name" but name is correct

Tags: sql-server

I would like to execute a query in a SQL Server database. I have two tables

**1.** `dbsCase_activity`

From this table, I need columns `due_date` and `follow_up_date`

**2.** `dbsCase_interval`

From this table, I need `id` and `end_date`

I have written a small piece of code for this, which works except for the `end_date`. When I add the `end_date`, I get the error:

> Invalid column name 'end_date'

But on the screenshot you can see that there is a column `end_date` and it is also written correctly:

[image: screenshot]

Do you have an idea how I can solve this?

```
SELECT 
    a.due_date, 
    a.follow_up_date, 
    i_due.id AS due_date_id, 
    i_follow_up.id AS follow_up_id
  --i_end_date.id AS end_date_id
FROM 
    [dbscasemanager_current].[dbo].[dbsCase_activity] a
LEFT JOIN 
    [dbscasemanager_current].[dbo].[dbsCase_interval] i_due ON a.due_date = i_due.id
LEFT JOIN 
    [dbscasemanager_current].[dbo].[dbsCase_interval] i_follow_up ON a.follow_up_date = i_follow_up.id
--LEFT JOIN [dbscasemanager_current].[dbo].[dbsCase_interval] i_end_date ON a.end_date = i_end_date.id
```

I tried the commented part from the code, that does not work

Comment: Have you looked into the table to tripple check that column exists in that database?  Maybe try MySQL Workbench to graphically poke around in there and see?

Comment: @easleyfixed yes, see here -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/GnS3U.png

Comment: Please show tables structure as DDL, not picture. Also it's not looks as MySQL, probably MSSQL used

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev ah you're right. It is MSSQL :-)
is that link better https://imgur.com/a/VyRvmIf

Comment: Your image of a column called end date in `dbsCase_interval` doesn't seem relevant, because the error is due to the fact that there isn't a column called `end_date` in `dbsCase_activity`

Comment: You're mixing your columns / tables. `i_end_date ON a.end_date = i_end_date.id` but `[dbsCase_activity] a`

Comment: @siggemannen what would be the correct statement?

"id" and "end_date" is in dbsCase_interval 
"due_date" and "follow_up_date" in dbsCase_activity

Comment: @GarethD yes because end_date is in dbsCase_interval. Can you tell me what would the correct statement look like?

Comment: `dbsCase_interval From this table, I need id and end_date` - you already join this table twice, why do you need another join to get end_date, you can already get it. it's almost like you don't know your own data, but surely noone else can figure out what you actually want to do

Comment: *"Can you tell me what would the correct statement look like?"* -Not really, because I don't know what columns are in `dbsCase_activity` nor do I know how you want to link this table for the 3rd join, all I do know though is that `end_date` is not in `dbsCase_activity`, because that is the source of your error.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. 
I solved it by myself. Thanks for the help. 

```
SELECT  
    internal_contract_number,
    subject,
    a.due_date, 
    i_due.id AS due_id, 
    i_due.end_date AS due_end_date,
    a.follow_up_date,
    i_follow_up.id AS follow_up_id,
    i_follow_up.end_date AS follow_up_end_date
FROM [dbscasemanager_current].[dbo].[dbsCase_activity] a
LEFT JOIN [dbscasemanager_current].[dbo].[dbsCase_interval] i_due ON a.due_date = i_due.id
LEFT JOIN [dbscasemanager_current].[dbo].[dbsCase_interval] i_follow_up ON a.follow_up_date = i_follow_up.id
```

Answer (score 2):

The screenshot shows the `dbsCase_**interval**` table. I expect the error refers to the `a.end_date` expression in the final (currently commented) `ON` clause, which uses an `end_date` column from the `dbsCase_**activity**` table.
*(emphasis added)*

Are you sure the `dbsCase_activity` table has a column named `end_date` that would match up with an `id` column in `dbsCase_interval`?

Are you sure **any** of the columns with `_date` as part of the name in `dbsCase_activity` will match up with the `id` column in `dbsCase_interval`, which looks to be a simple integer?